# Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]

Tags: sql

This error appear when write this code in sql server 2012:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select [ProductID],[ProductName],[UnitPrice] from Northwind.dbo.Products" queryout "d:\bcptest2.txt" -T  -c -t, '
```

Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you have made works correctly. However, you have not enabled TCP/IP within SQL Server. This can be done by doing the following:

1. Open up 'SQL Server Configuration Manager'
2. Select 'SQL Native Client Configuration'
3. On the right hand pane, right click on TCP/IP and select enable
4. Restart SQL Server Service

Your query should now work correctly.

See the following msdn document for further info. [Enable TCP/IP Network Procotol for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672.aspx)

Please let me know if this doesn't resolve the issue as there may be other configuration required.

EDIT:

Can you try running the following from the command line (i.e. cmd.exe):

```
 bcp "select [ProductID],[ProductName],[UnitPrice] from Northwind.dbo.Products" queryout "d:\bcptest2.txt" -T  -c -t
```

Let me know if this works for you or not (so we can see if it's BCP or xp_cmdshell causing the issue). Can you also look into the following:

1. SQL server is configured to allow remote connections

   - Within SSMS, right click the server name>Properties>Connections and tick the box 'Allow remote connections'
2. Is your user a sysadmin?
3. Where is your SQL server situated? (i.e. is it a local installation or on server on your network?)
4. Also is it an instance of SQL?

Comment: I've made some edits to the original post. Can you check those and let me know the results.